# ACPI Error: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000006) is beyond end of object (length 0x6) (20181213/exoparg2-396)

Tags: boot, kernel, acpi

I'm strugglin to install any linux distro in a new Samsung Odyssey machine (NP800G5H-XT2BR) with success.

After installation of any distro (ubuntu, fedora, debian), the computer:

- Freezes on Login screen
- It Boots but dont start any graphical screen

When running from a live iso (USB drive), I can install the system or use the computer, browse in internet, connect to wifi, bluetooth,  and so on.

But if i try to poweroff it freezes the machine forever. And I am force shutting down pressing the button.

My only clue is the boot log ACPI error:

```
[    7.181440] ACPI Error: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000006) is beyond end of object (length 0x6) (20181213/exoparg2-396)
[    7.181479] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PLD]
[    7.181480] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PLD]
[    7.181482] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._PLD, AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20181213/psparse-531)
[    7.181546] ACPI Error: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000007) is beyond end of object (length 0x6) (20181213/exoparg2-396)
[    7.181580] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PLD]
[    7.181581] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PLD]
[    7.181582] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._PLD, AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20181213/psparse-531)
```

My full boot log is here:

https://gist.github.com/sshnakamoto/ed3a768fe44351a02759445580f8aeff

Comment: Did you try to start with noacpi? This is not good to work forever like this, but this could help to determine if the problem relates to acpi.